# Unable to display aggregate graph within Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am receiving the following error when trying to ouptut a aggregate graph within jmeter:

```
2018-10-11 09:15:00,731 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out-of-bounds for length 13
    at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:440) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jorphan.gui.ObjectTableModel.getValueAt(ObjectTableModel.java:187) ~[jorphan.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.StatGraphVisualizer.getData(StatGraphVisualizer.java:638) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.StatGraphVisualizer.makeGraph(StatGraphVisualizer.java:594) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.StatGraphVisualizer.actionMakeGraph(StatGraphVisualizer.java:790) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at org.apache.jmeter.visualizers.StatGraphVisualizer.actionPerformed(StatGraphVisualizer.java:702) ~[ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.0 r1840935]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:270) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6589) ~[?:?]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6354) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2261) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4966) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2319) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4914) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4543) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4484) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2305) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4798) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$600(EventQueue.java:97) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,438 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [label]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,521 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [label]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,521 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [#_samples]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,521 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [median]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,521 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [90%_line]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,521 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [95%_line]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,521 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [99%_line]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,521 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [min]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,522 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [error_%]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,522 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [throughput]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,524 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [received_kb/sec]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,524 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [sent_kb/sec]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,551 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [label]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,552 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [label]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,552 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [label]
2018-10-11 09:15:04,552 WARN o.a.j.u.JMeterUtils: ERROR! Resource string not found: [label]
```

This means the graph cannot be generated and I am unsure how to fix the issue.

[image]

These are the results and settings of my aggregate graph, can anybody help me with this issue please?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known bug of JMeter 5.0:

- https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62770

It is fixed in nightly build:

- https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/dist/

And will be available in 5.1

Anyway, the best way to analyze your test is to use the Web Report which exists since 3.0 version:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html

Comment: Thank you :) Do you know what is the best alternative to use in terms of plugin? Would be cool to show a line graph or bar graph where we can see the response times for each label